# How I can read an RData file into Python? Cannot use rdata and pyreadr

Tags: python, r, rdata

Is there an alternative way to upload an RData file into Python without using the libraries `rdata` and `pyreadr` ?

I cannot use `rdata` because `EXTPTR` object is not implemented and cannot even use `pyreadr` because latin encoding is not supported

Comment: Have you already asked for help on the problems you're having with `rdata` and `pyreadr`?

Comment: Yes, there is not solution at the moment. I contacted the developers, it's a limit of both packages